# How can I build custom Word fields with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've found a question in stackoverflow: "How can I build Word fields with VBA" by JonnyGold.

I'm interested in the same question, but possibly on other reasons. The answers to JonnyGold question doesn't satisfy me. I'm still in MS-word 2003. My problem is to construct a custom word field, which would recognize a bookmark name around cursor location, saves that name in some custom variable/property, so that in a case of need a hyperlink of ref field could return a cursor to the said bookmark.

I need that mechanism to facilitate an easy work with a list of bibliographic sources, so that a user can by one click to go from a reference to a source and then to return back. Note that one source could be referenced in several different places and a user should be able to return to a reference, he/she clicked before.

I tried to use REF field with MACROBUTTON field inside, but MACROBUTTON requires double or one click on a button/text, which I want to avoid. I would like to create a field {RUNMACRO MacroName}, which would run a specified VDA Macro.

Comment: Can you send a link to his question?

Comment: here is a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217821/how-can-i-build-word-fields-with-vba

Comment: In my question on building custom MS-word fields with VBA instead of "cursor" should be "pointer" or "insertion point"